# I am trying to import a ConstraintLayout to my xml file

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting an error:No enum constant com.android.manifmerger.AttributeOperationType.CONTEXT.
when I am trying to use ConstraintLayout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5bGv.png)

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputFirstName"
        android:layout_width="398dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="188dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:hint="Enter your first name"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputLastName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.848" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputLastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:hint="Enter your last name"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUploadData"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/save_data"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputLastName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReadData"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/retrieve_data"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnUploadData"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewResultTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="FireStore data :"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnReadData" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewResultTitle"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.081" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I tried to use ConstraintLayout I deleted a  and put instead

This is what I found on the forums. It didn't work so I decided to return  and put in it "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout" but it also gave me an error. So I don't know how to fix it. Maybe it is because of that my xml file is in the manifest folder: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMKU2.png)
[Here is my dependencies in **build.gradle (:app)**:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6evB2.png)

**build.gradle (:app) File**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    // To use constraintlayout in compose
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot, you've replaced your `AndroidManifest.xml`'s contents with layout XML. That file is extremely important and you'll get all kinds of errors if you try to build without a valid one!

You need to revert it and then create a layout file (in the `res/layout` folder) for the layout XML you're trying to use